# Java NoclassDefFoundError while trying to use walrus for graph visualization

Tags: java, graph, walrus

I am getting this NoclassDefFoundError while trying to use walrus for graph visualization, although I installed J3D. I am using the following command to

```
java -cp  mp.jar;antlrall-mod.jar;libsea.jar;walrus.jar H3Main
```

on windows.

anybody can help?

Comment: NoClassDef on which clas? Where is this class in relation to your jars?

Comment: sorry it is on the class javax/media/j3d/canvas3D

Comment: And is that class inside any of those jars? Google search says it's in j3dcore, which I don't see on your classpath.

Comment: exactly I had to install java3d for that reason. Now I add all demanded jars and dll in the command but still have another error :

Comment: this is the command I use right now:
java -cp  mp.jar;antlrall-
mod.jar;libsea.jar;walrus.jar;"c:\Program Files\java\java3D\1.5.2\lib\ext\j3dcore.jar";"c:\Program Files\java\Java3D\1.5.2\lib\ext\j3dutils.jar";"c:\Program Files\java\Java3D\1.5.2\lib\ext\vecmath.jar";"c:\Program Files\java\Java3D\1.5.2\bin\j3dcore-ogl.dll" H3Main

Comment: and this is the error that I get:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no j3dcore-ogl in jav
a.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at javax.media.j3d.NativePipeline$1.run(NativePipeline.java:231)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.media.j3d.NativePipeline.loadLibrary(NativePipeline.java:200)
        at ...

Comment: It works the dll j3dcore-ogl.dll was missed from my computer.
Thank you very much

Comment: Ah, good job! I was just reading about that .dll and came back to comment about it